# Why SafeHtml only shows plain text & does not show formmatted text (GWT)?

Tags: html, gwt

```
    HTML myHtml=new HTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<i>Test</i>"));
    HTML myHtml2=new HTML("<i>Test2</i>");
    testHTMLPanel.add(myHtml);
    testHTMLPanel.add(myHtml2);
```

OUTPUT:

`<i>Test</i>`

*Test2*

The right output should be the formmatted text like the second one. Other Gwt html widget also have the similar problem.

I am using Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 2):

SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(String s)
HTML-escapes its argument and returns the result wrapped as a SafeHtml.

That means that you get somthing like &#6.0;i&#.62;Test&#.60;&#.47;i&.#62;

Check

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml

It's a security thing:
The reason why you have SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(userString) is that you can take a dynamic string, for example from a user input, and create a html text from it. It's more safe than just use Html.setText(userString) because with setText(userString) it would be feasible to inject vulnerable code.

more about input validation: http://www.testingsecurity.com/input-validation

Comment: but why when running in eclip , it show like plain text, no formatted text?

If i use SafehtmlBuilder then it shows correct format?

Comment: If use the SafeHtmlBuilder it will show exctely what you write. If you use a String it interprets the String as HTML so you can html-format your text with a string.

Comment: I confused!!, why when running in eclipe , it shows like plain text, no formatted text?

If i use SafehtmlBuilder then it shows correct format, why?

Comment: Ok, say, if I use Safehtml, if i deploy my app to become final application, then will users see the exact formatted text?

Comment: You will see what you wrote in your question: 1. <i>Test</i> 
2. test

Comment: Sorry I confused you. I want to know why google did it. If Safehtml does not show any html-formatted text, then why google create that method?
Since we just use setText & we got the same result, ie no html-formmatted text, just plain text

Comment: Ok i Understand now. I add the answer to my reply.

Comment: Ok, buddy, I understood what u mean, but it doesn't make sense to me that why the printed out result doesn't show correct format?
Then ho can we see if we coding correctly?